# pdf file generated by Doxygen and MikTex get wrong bookmarker for subgroup modules

Tags: pdf, doxygen, bookmarks, miktex

I defined a group and two sub groups in a .h file:

```
  /**

   * @defgroup groupDriver Drivers

   * @ingroup groupDriver

   * @{

   * @defgroup groupSPI SPI

  * @defgroup groupUART UART

  * @}

  */
```

And then use doxygen and Miktex to generate a pdf file.
I expect a bookmarker in the Modules Documentation Chapter like:

```
    Drivers

      --SPI

      --UART
```

but in fact a wrong bookmarker is generated:

```
    Drivers
    SPI
    UART
```

However, in the Module Index Chapter their hierarchy is right.

Answer (score 0):

I got the reasons after I have read the refman.tex file generated by Doxygen.
The Drivers module together with SPI and UART are all taken as a section of the same chapter.
We need to edit refman.tex manually for a right hierarchy.